# Check if there are two or more elements with same class and start some activity

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have three products with the following structure:
tickbox **|** label (same text but different label for value) **|** Qty dropdown (different input name)

They have three different label "classes":

1st - `<label for="related-checkbox-7087458-Z22-00026">`
2nd - `<label for="related-checkbox-7087458-Z22-00027">`
3rd - `<label for="related-checkbox-7087458-Z22-00028">`

The common between them is the text : ***"Free insurance included"***

I also have three QTY(quantity boxes) with different input names:

1st - `name="related_products[7087458][2536][qty]"`
2nd - `name="related_products[7087458][2537][qty]"`
3rd - `name="related_products[7087458][2538][qty]"`

So far I know how to change the quantity of the first one to "1" (by default 0), however I am not sure how can I target the second product with different ***"label for"*** property and different ***"input name"***. I've tried adding a second if statement but it seems that this did not work.

Please note that I am trying to change the QTY to one only for products containing the follwoing text: ***Free insurance included***

Please look at my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bn0uecn2/)

Comment: So if the label contains the text "Free insurance included", the input should have the value 1? Did you make the code, can you modify the HTML?

Comment: No unfortunately  I can not modify the code just the JS logic

Comment: Try to replace in your JS the input selector (line 7) by : var input = label.parentNode.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.querySelector('input[type="text"].input-qty');

Comment: @Zagonine Can you please add it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input selector in your JS is too specific.
Try to replace in your JS the selector (line 7) by :

```
var input = label.parentNode.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.querySelector('input[type‌​="text"].input-qty');
```